# Simple Java error, Beginner CS student

Tags: java

My errors when I press z are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at InputSum.main(InputSum.java:60)
```

Here's my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputSum
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   //declarations
      int sum;
      int number;
      int letter;
      boolean cont = true;
      boolean mop = true;

   //outputs

      System.out.println("Input ONLY Positive Integers including zero to Add (end with -1): ");


   //variables
      sum = 0;
      String numbers = "";

   //logic

      while(cont)  // loop
      {    
         number = input.nextInt();
         if(number == -1)
            break;
         // create a break for -1

         else if(number > -1)
         {sum = sum + number; numbers = numbers + number + ", "; } // summation of the numbers and string 

         else 
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Enter a valid input");
            // for non positive integers the output is invalid
      }



    //outputs and loops

      System.out.println("Entered numbers: " + numbers);
      System.out.println("The sum: " + sum);
      System.out.println("Would you like to continue with new inputs?(enter z for yes and any number other than 50 for no)");
      letter = input.nextInt();
      while(cont)
      {
         if(letter == 50){
            System.out.println("Input ONLY Positive Integers including zero to Add (end with -1): ");

            while(cont)  // loop
            {    
               number = input.nextInt();
               if(number == -1)
                  break;
               // create a break for -1

               else if(number > -1)
               {sum = sum + number; numbers = numbers + number + ", "; } // summation of the numbers and string 

               else 
                  System.out.println("Invalid input. Enter a valid input");
            // for non positive integers the output is invalid
            }

         }  
         else 

            System.exit(0); 
      }   // output and print statement for the sum

   }     
}
```

I don't know how to fix it, so when I hit z, it means yes, and doesn't give me these errors. how do i fix it?

Here is the instructions for the program:

> #### Exercise #1
>
> Write a program called InputSum that prompts the user to enter a
>   positive integer number. The program should accept integers until the
>   user enters the value -1 (negative one). After the user enters -1, the
>   program should display the entered numbers followed by their sum as
>   shown below.
>
> You must design the program such that it asks the user if they want to
>   continue with new inputs after each set of entries, ending the program
>   only when they do not respond to the question with "yes".
>
> Notice in the following sample run that -1 is not part of the output
>   that shows the "Entered numbers":
>
> ```
> Input numbers to add (end with -1): 10  2  13  50  100  -1
> Entered numbers: 10, 2, 13, 50, 100
> The Sum: 175
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? yes
>
> Input numbers to add (end with -1): 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  -1
> Entered numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
> The Sum: 55
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? yes
>
> Input numbers to add (end with -1): 1  1  1  1  100  -1
> Entered numbers: 1, 1, 1, 1, 100
> The Sum: 104
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? yes
>
> Input numbers to add (end with -1): 0  0  0  0  0  100  -1
> Entered numbers: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100
> The Sum: 100 
>
> Would you like to continue with new inputs? no    Make sure the program validates each entered number before processing it as
> ```
>
> the user may enter negative numbers other than the sentential value
>   -1. If it is a negative number that is not -1, then print out, "Invalid Input" and continue to accept numbers. Space out your outputs
>   as shown above.""

Comment: `"I don't know how to fix it, so [it] doesn't give me these errors."` -- What errors?  What input do you give your program?  What is your output (as opposed to the sample output from the assignment)?

Comment: Well, have you stepped through each line of code in the debugger?

Comment: Don't know how to fix what?

Comment: Dumping all of your code here and telling us to fix it for you isn't going to get you very far.  If you want to correct any errors you're seeing, the first step is to *read* those errors.

Comment: If you can narrow down your code to a specific problem, then it will be easier for others to offer help, rather than 'please do my homework for me' type questions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How about changing letter to a char ? If you're going to ask user to input a 'z' you need a primitive that can hold it.

Comment: > Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at
> java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)  at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
> InputSum.main(InputSum.java:60)

Answer (score 0):

At the point when you ask the user to enter "z", you use `letter = input.nextInt();` whereas you'd want to use `letter = input.next()` or `letter = input.nextLine()`since "z" is a string not an integer. Of course `letter` is an integer so you can't store a string in it and are therefore gonna need a new variable

Comment: here is my error is jgrasp:  >                                                          Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)  at
> java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)  at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
> java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
> InputSum.main(InputSum.java:60)